# Error deploying using kadirahq Mup

Tags: meteor, deployment, web-deployment

I am using Kadira's Meteor-Up (Mup) to deploy my meteor application. I have updated Mup from Mupx, which could be causing the problems.

Here is the config file

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
      one: { /* ssh auth details here */ }
    }
  },

  meteor: {
    name: 'soundcraft',
    path: '.',
    docker: {
      image: 'kadirahq/meteord',
    },
    servers: {
      one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
      debug: true,
      cleanAfterBuild: true,
    },
    "env": {
      "ROOT_URL": "http://139.232.218.147",
      "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://localhost:27017/soundcraft"
    },

    deployCheckWaitTime: 60
  },

  mongo: {
    oplog: true,
    port: 27017,
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
  },
};
```

The `mup setup` works fine, but when I use the `DEBUG=* mup deploy` command the following error is produced:

```
  mup:module:default exec => mup deploy +0ms
  mup:module:meteor exec => mup meteor deploy +2ms
  mup:module:meteor exec => mup meteor push +2ms
Building App Bundle Locally

Started TaskList: Pushing Meteor
[139.232.218.147] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to The Server
  nodemiral:sess:139.162.208.147 copy file - src: /tmp/62ab2c11-1477-4248-a409-392ca66940f0/bundle.tar.gz, dest: /opt/soundcraft/tmp/bundle.tar.gz, vars: undefined +0ms
[139.232.218.147] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to The Server: SUCCESS
[139.232.218.147] - Pushing the Startup Script
  nodemiral:sess:139.232.218.147 copy file - src: /Users/imac/.nvm/versions/node/v4.5.0/lib/node_modules/mup/lib/modules/meteor/assets/templates/start.sh, dest: /opt/soundcraft/config/start.sh, vars: {"appName":"soundcraft","useLocalMongo":1,"port":80,"logConfig":{"opts":{"max-size":"100m","max-file":10}},"docker":{"image":"kadirahq/meteord"}} +7s
[139.232.218.147] - Pushing the Startup Script: SUCCESS
  mup:module:meteor exec => mup meteor envconfig +3m

Started TaskList: Configuring  Meteor Environment Variables
[139.232.218.147] - Sending Environment Variables
  nodemiral:sess:139.232.218.147 copy file - src: /Users/imac/.nvm/versions/node/v4.5.0/lib/node_modules/mup/lib/modules/meteor/assets/templates/env.list, dest: /opt/soundcraft/config/env.list, vars: {"env":{"ROOT_URL":"http://139.232.218.147","MONGO_URL":"mongodb://localhost:27017/soundcraft","METEOR_SETTINGS":"{\"public\":{}}"},"appName":"soundcraft"} +433ms
[139.232.218.147] - Sending Environment Variables: SUCCESS
  mup:module:meteor exec => mup meteor start +456ms

Started TaskList: Start Meteor
[139.232.218.147] - Start Meteor
[139.232.218.147] x Start Meteor: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    Error response from daemon: No such container: soundcraft-frontend
    docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint soundcraft (22e4ffc6ecf94ffc1d35ebaf0e3f3364c92e3079439ca2e0138a5951b068f481): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use.
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    soundcraft
    Using default tag: latest
    latest: Pulling from kadirahq/meteord
    Digest: sha256:7ec54d5fafc11acbcc82f3e555fddce8e4742ddeda05a64997f2a10e3c04137e
    Status: Image is up to date for kadirahq/meteord:latest
    6e357baf5700be59d64973ff9653ca2eb80eaa2e52145411ce6d5d42d0a4d109
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After doing a little searching, I found something about getting docker to use a different port, so tried adding an extra line in the config to do so, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add port in env like below:

env: {
      PORT: 8010,
      ROOT_URL: "http://139.232.218.147",
      MONGO_URL: "mongodb://localhost:27017/soundcraft"
    },

Cheers,
Kosona

Answer (score 0):

I found the reasons and I want to share it with all of you.

With **mup setup** make sure that in your mup.js, your last line in each block end with space and not , . If the last block end with , you will see the process stuck and get timeout error.
Example:
The below is **correct**.
buildOptions: {
serverOnly: true,
debug: true,
cleanAfterBuild: true
},

The below will **generate error**
buildOptions: {
serverOnly: true,
debug: true,
cleanAfterBuild: true,
},

With **mup deploy** make sure that in your settings.json your last line in each block end with space and not , . If the last block end with , you will see the process stuck and get timeout error.
Example:
The below is **correct**.
"oAuth": {

"twitter": {

"consumerKey": "xxx",

"secret": "xxxx",
  "access_token_key": "xxx",
  "access_token_secret": "xxx"

},

"facebook": {

"appId": "xxx",

"secret": "xxxx"

}
}

The below will generate **error timeout**
"oAuth": {

"twitter": {

"consumerKey": "xxx",

"secret": "xxxx",
  "access_token_key": "xxx",
  "access_token_secret": "xxx"

},

"facebook": {

"appId": "xxx",

"secret": "xxxx"

},
}

HOPE THAT WILL HELP !

Cheers,
Kosona